# Show last line from text file in Label control

Tags: vb.net, file

I have this:

```vb
Label4.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("foo.txt")
```

How can I show only the last line of txt?

Comment: Use readalllines instead. It is an array of lines...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use [ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) that return an [IEnumerable(Of String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx), then ask for the last line

```
Label4.Text = File.ReadLines("foo.txt").Last()
```

instead if you want to get a specific line of which you know the index number in the file skipping al the previous lines you could write something like this

```
Dim lineIndex as Integer = GetLineIndex() ' Supposed to return the line index required
Label4.Text = File.ReadLines("foo.txt").Skip(lineIndex-1).Take(1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will ask how can i set line that i want to show directly? like dont use just Last.

Comment: This is very different problem unless you have the index number of that line (Ie. Want to show the X line in the file where X-1 is the count of lines to be skipped from the start of the file.)

Comment: Ok, when I know exactly what line I want to see so how would I change this line in this scenario?

Comment: _File.ReadLines("foo.txt").Skip(x-1).Take(1)_